# how will I display random math questions from my javascript to my html page but the numbers to be generated are not showing just the signs

Tags: javascript

I aam trying to create a math game for kids that will ask the player his name and the player to select the  level he is playing ,how will I display random math questions from my javascript to my html page but the numbers to be generated are not showing just the signs, this is my script i linked it to my html externally.
here's my code:

```
var pageName = location.pathname.split("/").slice(-1);
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
  alert(pageName);
  randomOpr();
  pageAction();
});
var num1 = document.getElementById("num1");
var num2 = document.getElementById("num2");
function pageAction() {
  if (pageName == "level1.html") {
    num1.innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20 + 1);
    num2.innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20 + 1);
  } else if (pageName == "level2.html") {
    num1.innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random() * 30 + 21);
    num2.innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random() * 30 + 21);
  } else if (pageName == "level3.html") {
    num1.innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50 + 51);
    num2.innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50 + 51);
  }
}
var operators = ['+', '-', '*', '/']
var selectedOperator = Math.floor(Math.random() * operators.length);

function randomOpr() {
  var operator = document.getElementById("opr");
  alert((operator).value);
  operator.innerHTML = operators[selectedOperator];
}

function checkMath() {
  var num1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("num1").innerHTML, 10);
  var num2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("num2").innerHTML, 10);
  var answer = parseInt(document.getElementById("answer").value, 10);
  if (operators[selectedOperator] == "+") {
    if (answer === num1 + num2) {
      alert("your answer is correct");
    } else {
      alert(answer + " is incorrect, correct answer is " + (num1 + num2));
    }
  } else if (operators[selectedOperator].sign == "-") {
    if (answer === num1 - num2) {
      alert("your answer is correct");
    } else {
      alert(answer + " is incorrect, correct answer is " + (num1 - num2));
    }
  } else if (operators[selectedOperator].sign == "*") {
    if (answer === num1 - num2) {
      alert("your answer is correct");
    } else {
      alert(answer + " is incorrect, correct answer is " + (num1 * num2));
    }
  } else if (operators[selectedOperator].sign == "/") {
    if (answer === num1 - num2) {
      alert("your answer is correct");
    } else {
      alert(answer + " is incorrect, correct answer is " + (num1 / num2));
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("answer").value = "";
  randomNum();
}
```

Comment: add your html code

Comment: Well does pagename match correctly? Add simple debugging and find out

Comment: `num1 + num2` could return `11` instead of `2` if both num1 and num2 equal `1` and are strings for example

Comment: @pokeybit OP is using `parseInt()`.

Comment: FYI - Don't use `.innerHTML` unless the string has HTML in it, otherwise use `.textContent` or, if you are setting/getting values of form fields, use `.value`. Also, why `20 + 1` and `30 + 21` and `50 + 51` and not just `21`, `51` and `101`?

Comment: @ScottMarcus apoloogies I missed that

Comment: You should also clean up your code. In one case, you've got global variables of `num1` and `num2` that point to elements (i.e. `var num1 = document.getElementById("num1");`) and then in the `checkMath` function, you are shadowing those same two variables with the Integer within those elements (i.e. `var num1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("num1").innerHTML, 10);`). This adds confusion to your code. Rename your variables to accurately reflect what they reference/store.

Comment: `<body>
    <div class="form-group">
        Hi, please enter your Name: <input type="text" name="name" required>
    </div>
          <div class="form-group">
                What level would you like to play:
                <a href ="level1.html" >Level 1</a> 
                <a href ="level2.html"  >Level 2</a>
                <a href ="level3.html"  >Level 3</a>>
                
            </div>
    <br>
    <br> 
   

    </form> 
    </body>
</html>` @TomMendelson

Answer (score 0):

Cleaned up the code as suggested in the comments.

No need to get the numbers in the question a second time (already have them when generated).

No need to repeat the answer check and alert code for each operator.

What was 'sign' in 'operators[selectedOperator].sign' in three of the four checks? - removed.

What was randomNum()? - removed.

I'd also check values for the divide questions...

```
<body>

    <div id="num1"></div>
    <div id="opr"></div>
    <div id="num2"></div>
    <div>
        <input type=text id="answer">
    </div>
    <button id="btnAnswer">Check answer</button>

    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#btnAnswer").click(checkMath)
        });

        // Set up re-usable variables first.
        var pageName = location.pathname.split("/").slice(-1);
        var operators = ['+', '-', '*', '/']
        var num1 = document.getElementById("num1");
        var num2 = document.getElementById("num2");
        var answerInput = document.getElementById("answer");
        var operator = document.getElementById("opr");
        // The values of the numbers to use in the question, current Operator, and calculated answer.
        var leftNumber = 0;
        var rightNumber = 0;
        var selectedOperator = "";
        var answer = 0;


        window.addEventListener('load', function () {
            alert(pageName);
            pageAction();
        });

        function pageAction() {
            // Use a switch to perform the check on the level, then set the multiplier.
            var multiplier = 0;

            switch (pageName) {
                case "level1.html":
                    multiplier = 20;
                    break;
                case "level2.html":
                    multiplier = 30;
                    break;
                case "level3.html":
                    multiplier = 50;
                    break;
                default:
                    multiplier = 20;
                    break;
            }

            // Generate the numbers, set them on the page, and get a random Operator.
            leftNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * multiplier + 1);
            rightNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * multiplier + 1);
            num1.innerText = leftNumber;
            num2.innerText = rightNumber;
            answerInput.value = "";
            randomOpr();

            // Calculate the answer for later use.
            switch (selectedOperator) {
                case "+":
                    answer = leftNumber + rightNumber;
                    break;
                case "-":
                    answer = leftNumber - rightNumber;
                    break;
                case "*":
                    answer = leftNumber * rightNumber;
                    break;
                case "/":
                    answer = leftNumber / rightNumber;
                    break;
                default:
                    answer = leftNumber + rightNumber;
                    break;
            }
        }


        function randomOpr() {
            // Set the current Operator, update the page control.
            selectedOperator = operators[Math.floor(Math.random() * operators.length)];
            operator.innerText = selectedOperator;
            alert((operator).innerText);
        }

        function checkMath() {
            // Check submitted answer against the calculated one, then re-run for another question.
            var submittedAnswer = parseInt(answerInput.value, 10);

            if (submittedAnswer === answer) {
                alert("your answer is correct");
            } else {
                alert(submittedAnswer + " is incorrect, correct answer is " + answer);
            }
            pageAction();
        }

    </script>

</body>
```